# Django AbstractUser, Login Forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-settings

I Got Error, class LoginForm(User):
TypeError: **str() argument 'encoding' must be str, not tuple.**
My Question, How To Call "AUTH_USER_MODEL" from forms.py.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, 
BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email                   = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    full_name               = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    create_account          = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_reviewer             = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

settings.py

```
#User model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Account

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class LoginForm(User):
    pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are inheriting Model class on forms.py, have a look at Forms.ModelForm for making use of existing model inside form

Comment: Thank for the answer, Maybe i should be using LoginForm(UserCreationForm).